# Remove parentheses from list in apex

Tags: apex, json, list

I have this list. when i print it:

```
System.debug(listaCot);

//it shows this
({"Cdocu":"31","Ndocu":"","Item":2,"Codi":"0301-011626","Codf":"45TEL080075C009"}), 
({"Cdocu":"31","Ndocu":"","Item":2,"Codi":"0301-011626","Codf":"45TEL080075C009"})
```

I want to show it like this:

```
{"Cdocu":"31","Ndocu":"","Item":2,"Codi":"0301-011626","Codf":"45TEL080075C009"}, 
{"Cdocu":"31","Ndocu":"","Item":2,"Codi":"0301-011626","Codf":"45TEL080075C009"}
```

How can i do that? I need to pass it as a json to an API. My problem is that when I'm passing it, it goes with the parentheses and I'm trying to remove them.

Comment: What is your overall objective? Are you trying to serialize some data into JSON?

Comment: You can't alter how System.debug debugs things to the log. That said, what we probably have here is an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your underlying "X"? What situation are you trying to solve? Please read about [ask], then [edit] your question to include any additional information so we can assist you.

Comment: It's a list that I'm passing it to an API but it goes with the parentheses and I'm trying to remove them.